# $f_n:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}, f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x+n}$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to prove that the functions
$$ f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x+n} $$
defined on the set of positive real numbers are linearly independent, i.e. proving
$$ a_1f_1(x)+\cdots+a_Nf_N(x)=0 $$
for all $x$ implies $a_1=\ldots=a_N=0$ (for all natural $\mathbb N$).

I could do the small cases easily "by hand" by multiplying everything by $(x+1)\ldots(x+N)$ and setting all new coefficients to 0 and solving the obtained linear system of equations. However induction gets way too messy this way. 
I also concluded $\sum \frac{a_i}{(x+i)^m}$ for all natural $m.$ Assuming the existence of $a_i$'s not all 0 would imply that the set 
$$\left\{\left(\frac{1}{(x+1)^m},\ldots,\frac{1}{(x+n)^m}\right)\in \mathbb{R}^n : x>0, m\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$ is contained in a $(n-1)$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which seems highly unlikely. However I can't make it rigorous.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is calculus allowed?

Comment: How much calculus?

Comment: Basic calculus yes.

Comment: Enough calculus to know that $\int \frac{1}{x+k} dx = \ln(x+k) + C\,$.

Comment: yes that's fine

Comment: If you integrate, you'll get in the end something like $\,\prod (x+k)^{a_k} = \text{const}\,$. But the product is unbounded unless all exponents are $0\,$ (well, with a few special cases to be handled separately, so take this as just a possible hint).

Comment: How can you know that the product is unbounded? the exponents do NOT all need to be positive, e.g. $a_1=1,a_2=-1$.

Comment: Right, that's one of those *special cases*.

Comment: not really because the sum of the $a_i$'s is always 0.

Comment: Consider using \ldots to get $a_1\ldots a_N$ and \cdots to get $a_1 + \cdots + a_N$.

Comment: @FriederJäckel Too long for a comment, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that there is some $N\geq 1$ and real numbers $c_1,\dots,c_N$ such that
$$ c_1f_1(x)+\dots+c_Nf_N(x)=0$$
for all $x>0$. Multiplying both sides by $(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+N)$, we get
$$ \sum_{n=1}^Nc_n\prod_{\substack{m=1\\m\neq n}}^N(x+m)=0$$
for all $x>0$.

But the left-hand side is a polynomial, and so must be the zero polynomial. In particular, the identity above must hold for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then for each $n$, setting $x=-n$ yields
$$ 0=c_n\prod_{\substack{m=1\\m\neq n}}^N(m-n)$$
which implies that $c_n=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;F(x) = \prod_{k=1}^N (x+k)^{a_k}\,$, then $\,F'(x)=F(x) \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{a_k}{x+k}\,$ for $\,\forall x \in X = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{-1, \cdots, -N\}\,$.

Suppose that $\,a_k\,$ existed such that $\,\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{a_k}{x+k}=0\,$ for $\,\forall x \in X\,$, then that would imply that $\,F'(x)=0\,$ on $\,X\,$, so $\,F(x)\,$ is piecewise constant on $X$. That, in turn, means that none of the $\,a_k\,$ can be strictly negative, since a negative exponent $\,a_j\,$ would have $\,F(x)\,$ unbounded in the vicinity of $\,x = -j\,$. With all the exponents non-negative, $\,F(x)\,$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and so constant on $\,\mathbb{R}\,$. If not *all* $\,a_k = 0\,$, then there exists an $\,a_j \gt 0\,$. But, in that case $\,F(-j) = 0 \ne F(0) = \prod_{k=1}^N k^{a_k}\,$, so $\,F\,$ cannot be constant. Therefore all the coefficients $\,a_k=0\,$.